# Not jar file in library

Tags: android, jar

I know this is a question of a newbie, but I've been looking for over 3 hours and not find the answer ..

I want to implement a library in a test application, but until now, all I have used libraries are included in the project through a file "jar"

I'm finding libraries like this:

https://github.com/walkingice/gui-sliding-sidebar

... where there is no file type "jar"

Honestly, I do not know how to add these libraries to my project, I read about this:

```
$ Git clone <this project>

$ Cd <project>

$ Android update project-p.

$ Debug install android
```

I do not know if it is related

Sorry for the inconvenience and appreciate the help

regards

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile that3rd party project, which will create a jar (most likely; otherwise you need to create the jar to contain all the generated .class files yourself); then reference that jar as you do with the others.

Comment: "You will need to compile that3rd party project, Which will create a jar"
As I have to do this compilation?

Really, sorry for the inconvenience. 

regards

Comment: You don't have to, you can copy-paste parts of the code to your project as well, but it is easier to compile the whole library/application than understand what bits and pieces you will need exactly

Answer (score 0):

> I'm finding libraries like this:

It is not a library. It is an application.

> Honestly, I do not know how to add these libraries to my project

You copy the relevant bits of source code (and possibly resources) from that project into your own project.

> I read about this:

The actual instructions on the project page will install the application on a device or emulator.

Comment: Hi, I have copied parts of the code in my project, but I get the standard errors when something is not imported.

I used this example because it is easier.

https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

In the activity, I get error in the line of import:

android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu.SateliteClickedListener import;

and thus all that in the code refers to SatelliteMenu.

Also in the xml layout, it gives me error on line:

   <android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
      .... />

I do not understand how to apply this to my project.

Again, appreciate the help

regards